Convert JSON dictionary file to CSV
Need to extract recordID, date, title, and breakout action_history data.  Since the action_history data also has the recordID, it does not all have to be on the same row for the CSV file.  Here's the JSON string:
{
"783": {        
        "recordID": 783,
        "title": "Test1",
        "date": 1723572991,        
        "action_history": [
            {
                "recordID": 783,               
                "time": 1723573283,                
                "actionType": "submit"               
            },           
            {
                "recordID": 783,               
                "time": 1723573425,               
                "actionType": "Save"
            },
            {
                "recordID": 783,               
                "time": 1723585061,
                "actionType": "Complete"
            }
        ]       
    },
"900": {        
        "recordID": 900,
        "title": "Test2",
        "date": 1723572825,        
        "action_history": [
            {
                "recordID": 900,               
                "time": 1723573300,                
                "actionType": "submit"               
            },           
            {
                "recordID": 900,               
                "time": 1723573350,               
                "actionType": "Save"
            },
            {
                "recordID": 900,               
                "time": 1723585390,
                "actionType": "Complete"
            }
        ]       
    }
}

Not getting very far with just the basic json.load and csv conversion methods.  With this JSON dictionary structure (not an array), I'm having trouble breaking out the action_history for each recordID. The action_history can be in different rows since the recordID is indicated (I can join the records later).
File output:
recordID,title,date,action_history
783,Test1,1723572991,"[{'recordID': 783, 'time': 1723573283, 'actionType': 'submit'}, {'recordID': 783, 'time': 1723573425, 'actionType': 'Save'}, {'recordID': 783, 'time': 1723585061, 'actionType': 'Complete'}]"
900,Test2,1723572825,"[{'recordID': 900, 'time': 1723573300, 'actionType': 'submit'}, {'recordID': 900, 'time': 1723573350, 'actionType': 'Save'}, {'recordID': 900, 'time': 1723585390, 'actionType': 'Complete'}]"

Preferred output:
recordID,title,date,actionType,time
783,Test1,1723572991,"submit",1723573283
783,Test1,1723572991,"Save",1723573425
783,Test1,1723572991,"Complete",1723585061
900,Test2,1723572825,"submit",1723573300
900,Test2,1723572825,"Save",1723573350
900,Test2,1723572825,"Complete",1723585390


Script:
import csv
import json

def json_to_csv(json_file, csv_file):

    with open(json_file) as f:
        data = json.load(f)

        f = csv.writer(open(csv_file, "w+", newline=""))

        f.writerow(["recordID","title","date","action_history"])
        for x in data.values():
            f.writerow([x["recordID"],
                        x["title"],
                        x["date"],
                        x["action_history"]])

#src, dest, function call
json_file = 'source.json'
csv_file = 'output.csv'
json_to_csv(json_file, csv_file)


This question is similar to: How can I convert JSON to CSV?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Have you looked at pandas.json_normalize()?

I have.  But pandas did not seem to handle the dictionary formats well.  But that does not mean I'm using it correctly; I've simply hit a wall with my limited knowledge.

The following code was provided by another user "snippsat" on python-forum.io:
import csv
import json
 
def json_to_csv(json_file, csv_file):
    with open(json_file) as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        f = csv.writer(open(csv_file, "w+", newline=""))
        header = ["recordID", "actionType", "time"]
        f.writerow(header)
        # Iterate through each record in the JSON data
        for record in data.values():
            record_id = record["recordID"]
            for action in record["action_history"]:
                f.writerow([record_id, action["actionType"], action["time"]])
 
json_file = 'Simple.json'
csv_file = 'output.csv'
json_to_csv(json_file, csv_file)


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

you can try:
import csv
import json

def json_to_csv(json_file, csv_file):

    with open(json_file) as f:
        data = json.load(f)

        f = csv.writer(open(csv_file, "w+", newline=""))
        header = ["recordID","title","date",
                  "action_Submit_time",
                  "action_Save_time",
                  "action_Complete_time"
                  ]
        f.writerow(header)
        for x in data.values():            
            result = [x["recordID"],
                    x["title"],
                    x["date"],
                ]
            
            result.extend( [ j["time"] for j in  x["action_history"] ]) 
                
            f.writerow(result)

#src, dest, function call
json_file = 'source.json'
csv_file = 'output.csv'
json_to_csv(json_file, csv_file)

short:
result = [  x["recordID"],
            x["title"],
            x["date"]] + [j["time"] for j in x.get("action_history", [])]


This is very helpful...but, I neglected to explain in my question that the actionType may not be in order and can occur multiple times in each recordID.  Ideally, I'd like to get each actionType in its own row.  Perhaps the "title" column could contain the actionType.

@Shwfgd If you neglected something in the question, edit the question to be more accurate.
